# What are all the considerations to be taken care while moving from Play! framework to Springs/Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, annotations, playframework-2.0

I was working on Web development project using Java, Scala, JPA, Ajax, HTML, CSS, Javascript etc. But now due to some problems like 'lack of resource persons on Play framework in my team' we have decided to move to the **Spring/Hibernate** framework. So we need to convert the complete project in Spring/Hibernate framework. So what are all the considerations to be taken care while doing the same? Whether to use Hibernate annotations or do we need to proceed only with hbm and xml files? We are using MySQL as a database.

Comment: XML was cool 15 years ago. Use standard JPA annotations (and use the JPA standard API rather than the Hibernate proprietary API)

Answer (score 0):

It's very general question. So the answer could be as well.

1. If you want to move from Play to Spring, then you want to leave scala as well. You wrote that you have scala in your current project. Then .... You will need completely rewrite your that part.
2. You use play and MySQL and want to move to the Hibernate. Then be sure that you use in the Play JPA for the access to the Database (or you can even use Hibernate if you want). After this migration to Hibernate in Spring would be easy.
3. In general ... It could be more easy just write a new project on Spring based on the current business cases.